# Google Chrome logo using Android

Tags: java, android

I couldn't find a similar example as close as the Google chrome logo. I want to make this logo using Android, forget about the colors or exact design. Imagine the blue dot is an ImageView, the red,green and yellow are ImageButtons. I want an ImageView surrounded by 3 or 4 ImageButtons like this. All what I came up to is the Oval layout shape with ImageView centered. I only need a hint if anybody has.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Chrome_Logo.svg and http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e2/Google_Chrome_icon_%282011%29.svg are SVG versions of the chrome logo.  You should be able to get quite exact coordinates from those.